# (NS3 with NS3 NetSimulyzer Module Installed) Exception: Couldn't find the specified program: mobility-buildings-example

Tags: ns-3

very new to using NS3 and I'm currently attempting to use it with NetSimulyzer for a research project.

I had cloned NS3 into my Ubuntu-VM and cloned the NetSimulyzer module into ns-3-dev-git/src folder.

I had then configured NS3 with --build-profile=debug --enable-examples --enable-tests

NetSimulyzer was recognized as a module and ns3 was successfully built, with testing the tutorial files first.cc, second.cc, and third.cc being successfull as well.

However, when performing the command ./ns3 run mobility-buildings-example to compile mobility-buildings-example.cc and create a .json file, it states that:

[Exception: Couldn't find the specified program: mobility-buildings-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVjvd.png)

I am mainly interested in having this example compile, create a .json file, and have it visualized in my NetSimuylzer.

I have tried:

Installing the NS3 NetSimuylzer module into ns-3-dev-git/contrib as recommended by their github ReadMe: https://github.com/usnistgov/NetSimulyzer-ns3-module

Searching online for solutions similar to my issue, however majority relate to other NS3/NetSimulyzer issues, none discussing about the NetSimulyzer module.

Configuring/Building ns-allinone-3.38 and going through the same process.

Answer (score 0):

before running your script in NS3 you should first build using this command:

(supposing you are in the main directory project(the directory that includes ns3 executable))

```
./ns3 build
```

and as the ns3 build searches for the new files to build them, you should put your script in a directory which ns3 can find it. the default location for the ns3 to look for new files is "main-directory/scratch".

so it is recommended to put your file in this directory so that ns3 will be able to find it and build it.

the after building it, you can easily run the following command to run your script and you should be good to go.

```
./ns3 run scratch/<file_name>
```

feel free if you have further questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CMakeLists.txt file from the netsimulyzer module, you will notice the example names have a `-netsimulyzer` suffix.

https://github.com/usnistgov/NetSimulyzer-ns3-module/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt#L52

The correct command is `./ns3 run mobility-buildings-example-netsimulyzer`.